# Using Handlebars how do I wrap 4 divs in a row div?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I had a hard time wording the question so I apologize. I'm using handlebars to generate listings from a JSON file and I'm stuck. Basically every 4 cards I generate need to be wrapped in a row div. Here's what I tried but didn't work very well

(using coffeescript)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "everyOther", (index, amount, scope) ->
  if index % amount
    scope.inverse this
  else
    scope.fn this
```

Here's my template

```
{{#each data}}
  {{#everyOther @index 4}}
    <div class = "card-result-row">
   {{/everyOther}}
     <div class = "card-result with-image">
      <img src="{{this.userImgUrl}}" alt="Contacts Image" />
      <div class="contact-info">
        <a href="{{this.userUrl}}"> {{this.user}}</a>
        <span class="contact-title">{{this.jobTitle}}</span>
        <span class="contact-email"><a href="mailto:{{this.email}}" title="Send Email">{{this.email}}</a></span>
        <span class="meta-location"><a href="{{this.locLink}}">{{this.location}}</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
   {{#everyOther @index 4}}
    </div>
   {{/everyOther}}
{{/each}}
```

So basically on the first iteration I want it to open a row div and after the 4th "card" is generated I want to close out that row and start a new one. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do is not a good practice in Handlebars as in other logic-less templaters. It will be much better if you make data transformation before passing it to template, instead of inventing such strange helpers.

If you try to group your data first, for example using underscore.js [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```
data = _.toArray(
  _.groupBy(data, function (item, index) {
    return Math.floor(index/4);
  })
);
```

Then your template will look like:

```
{{#each data}}
  <div class = "card-result-row">
    {{#each this}}
      <div class = "card-result with-image">
        <img src="{{userImgUrl}}" alt="Contacts Image" />
        <div class="contact-info">
          <a href="{{userUrl}}"> {{user}}</a>
          <span class="contact-title">{{jobTitle}}</span>
          <span class="contact-email"><a href="mailto:{{email}}" title="Send Email">{{email}}</a></span>
          <span class="meta-location"><a href="{{locLink}}">{{location}}</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

This template cleaner and much easy to read, isn't it?

Comment: The template is much cleaner! Good advice from separating the model from the view and showing _underscore.